# Diffined pie chart color googlechart

Tags: charts, google-visualization

i am trying to change pie chart color like
data A --> Orange
data B --> Red

any suggestion to resolved this probleme
any suggestion to resolved this probleme
thanks for help

```
google.charts.load('current', { packages: ['corechart'] });
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(draw_Charts);
        function draw_Charts() {
            var options = {
                backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                width: '100%',
                height: 400,
                title: 'Project Status',
                titleTextStyle: {
                    fontSize: 20,
                },

                legend: { position: 'left', textStyle: { fontSize: '40%' } },
                colors: ['#3E7CB1', '#054A91']
            };
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "progress_project.asmx/GetPiChartEx",
                data: '{}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (r) {
                    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(r.d);
                    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart($("#Extend_Pie")[0]);
                    chart.draw(data, options);
                     updateChart();
                },
                failure: function (r) {
                    alert(r.status + " - " + r.statusText);
                },
                error: function (r) {
                    alert(r.status + " - " + r.statusText);
                }
            });
            
        }
```